# Dropzone client side resize with file upload to AWS pre-signed url

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dropzone.js, dropzone

I implemented image file upload to an AWS s3 bucket with dropzone. It creates a pre-signed url and ultimately sends the image file to s3. I cannot get this to work in combination with the client side image resizing dropzone provides.

For s3 upload to work properly, I had to override `sending`, as explained here https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/590. Otherwise, it would send form data and I would get the image wrapped in `------WebKitFormBoundary...`

This, from the link above is working:

```
  sending: function(file, xhr) {
    var _send = xhr.send;
    xhr.send = function() {
      _send.call(xhr, file);
    };
  }
```

However, I get problems when I try to combine the above approach with dropzone's client side image resize. As per the dropzone documentation, I specified:

```
  resizeWidth: 384,
  resizeHeight: 384,
  resizeMethod: 'contain',
  resizeQuality: 1.0,
```

Debugging the code, the resize functionality is called with the above settings. However, the `file` that arrives at sending is still the original file which has not been resized. I could not make out where the resized image would be stored.

I tried to change `sending` as follows:

```
sending (file, xhr) {
  var _send = xhr.send;

  this.options.transformFile.call(this, file, function (done) {
    console.log('done', done)
    xhr.send = function () {
      _send.call(xhr, done);
    }
  }
```

However, the result from the call to `transformFile` is a blob and, while the result looks resized, it is also wrapped as a form.

In summary, can I get the combination of resize with plain image upload to work, somehow? Is the resized image stored in a suitable place? Can my override of `sending` be changed to get this to function?

Answer (score 2):

I just created an account to answer this since I've been trying to do the same thing for the last hours.

I was on the same track as what you did, except I removed the `resizeWidth` and `resizeHeight` params to prevent double processing, and called `resizeImage` instead.

After messing with logs for a while it hit me, it was a race condition! The function `sending` returned before `xhr` got modified. Specifically, in `createThumbnail` there is a `FileReader` that executes async. Your result was resized and wrapped because the `xhr` did not get changed at all, so it just executed the normal code path.

Thus, just calling the resizing function in `xhr.send` does the trick!

Here is my working code:

```
sending: function(file, xhr) {
    var _send = xhr.send;
    var _this = this
    xhr.send = function () {
        _this.resizeImage(file, 500, 500, 'contain', function (done) {
            _send.call(xhr, done);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your findings and the analysis of what went wrong! I asked the same question on github, sorry I should have updated here and it might have saved you the hassle. Will add a separate answer now...

Comment: Works for me, and seems to be the only way to do this when using the PUT variety of pre-signed S3 uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same on github and pkl's solution (https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1840#issuecomment-538643878) worked for me:

```
xhr.send = formData => {
  // get the resized file in formData.get("file") vs file
  _send.call(xhr, formData.get("file"));
 };
```

also, joshmaines posted (https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1840#issuecomment-545590304):

> You could also override the process queue and implementing it in the
>   thumbnail function instead: this.on('thumbnail', function(file, thumb)
>   { file.thumbnail = thumb; this.processQueue(); });